# ActiveMQ Classic no durable subscribers

Tags: activemq-classic

ActiveMQ Classic v5.17.1 on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Using async-mqtt and associated tools.

I have a javascript publisher and print the published message

```
{"cmd":"publish","topic":"mytopic","payload":"xyz","qos":1,"retain":true,"messageId":55994,"dup":false}
```

I use the mqtt utility to subscribe, specifying no-clean and a clientId, thinking this will give me a durable subscription

```
npx mqtt sub --no-clean -client-id DAVE --qos 1 --verbose -t "mytopic"
```

In the ActiveMQ console I see this subscription show up as non-durable, and indeed if I disconnect for a while on reconnection I see only new messages.

My ActiveMQ broker is configured with persistence enabled.

What am I missing? How can I demonstrate durable subscription behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a couple of problems here...

If you look at the "help" for the `sub` command you see this:

```
$ npx mqtt help sub
Usage: mqtt subscribe [opts] [topic]

Available options:

  -h/--hostname HOST    the broker host
  -p/--port PORT        the broker port
  -i/--client-id ID     the client id
  -q/--qos 0/1/2        the QoS of the message
  --no-clean            do not discard any pending message for
                        the given id
  -t/--topic TOPIC      the message topic
  -k/--keepalive SEC    send a ping every SEC seconds
  -u/--username USER    the username
  -P/--password PASS    the password
  -l/--protocol PROTO   the protocol to use, 'mqtt',
                        'mqtts', 'ws' or 'wss'
  --key PATH            path to the key file
  --cert PATH           path to the cert file
  --ca PATH             path to the ca certificate
  --insecure            do not verify the server certificate
  --will-topic TOPIC    the will topic
  --will-message BODY   the will message
  --will-qos 0/1/2      the will qos
  --will-retain         send a will retained message
  -v/--verbose          print the topic before the message
  -H/--help             show this
```

You're specifying `-client-id` rather than `--client-id` (notice the extra `-`) like the `help` indicates.

However, the `help` is **actually incorrect** because `--client-id` doesn't work either. **You must use either `--clientId` or `-i`.**

Both of these gave me the expected result:

```
npx mqtt sub --no-clean --clientId DAVE --qos 1 --verbose -t "mytopic"
```

```
npx mqtt sub --no-clean -i DAVE --qos 1 --verbose -t "mytopic"
```

I sent [a PR](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/pull/1643) to get this fixed.